# Typescript Union Type with certain keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type:

```
Record<string, string | Record<"like" | "in", string>>
```

It should accept only strings or objects with the keys "like" and "in" as a value for an object. For example

```
{key: { like: "xxxx"}}
{key: {in: "xxxx"}}
{key1: { like: "xxxx"}, key2: {in: "xxxxx"}, key3: "xxx"}
{key1: "xxx", key2: {like: "xxxxx"}}
{key: "xxx"}
```

But when I pass an object like this {key: {like: "xxxx"} }, it throws an error like:

`Property 'in' is missing in type '{ like: string; }' but required in type 'Record<"like" | "in", string>'`

How can I create a type for this kind of case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the built-in [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type, which will make the `like` and `in` optional:

```
type FilterType = Record<string, Partial<Record<'like' | 'in', string>>>;
```

Testing:

```
const case1: FilterType = { key: { like: 'xxxx' } };
const case2: FilterType = { key: { in: 'xxxx' } };
const case3: FilterType = {
  key1: { like: 'xxxx' },
  key2: { in: 'xxxxx' },
  key3: 'xxx', // error
};
const case4: FilterType = { key1: 'xxx', key2: { like: 'xxxxx' } }; // error
const case5: FilterType = { key: 'xxx' }; // error
```

Though this approach will allow you to keep the property empty, and if you want to require at least one of them we will need to create a type like this:

```
Record<'like' | 'in', string> |
Record<'like', string> |
Record<'in', string>
```

Let's create a separate type for the operator:

```
type Operator = 'like' | 'in';
```

Now, create a type for the whole object:

```
type FilterType = Record<string, FilterProperty>;
```

And in the `FilterProperty` we will accept a generic argument constrained by `Operator` to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which will allow us to create a separate record type for every member of the union:

```
type FilterProperty<T extends Operator = Operator> =
  | Record<T, string>
  | (T extends T ? Record<T, string> : never);
```

Testing:

```
const case5: FilterType = { key: {} }; // error
```